# Error while pushing changes into GERRIT

Tags: git, gerrit

I have created a project on gerrit. After which I cloned it on my local machine, made a few changes, added the changes, committed them and when I tried to push the changes, I am getting the following error,

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 406 Not Acceptable while accessing http://host_ip:port/new_proj/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

It is not allowing me to push any changes. Bellow are the list of commands I followed,

```
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

I do not know where I am going wrong and need guidance.

Comment: What version of gerrit & git?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/repo-discuss/apqgC-Nxgfc/3meOC8USmSgJ

Comment: My git version is 1.7.1 and gerrit version is 2.11 . My git version is really old. I should probably upgrade it. But, I have another gerrit instance running on my local machine to which I am able to push changes. What am I missing?

Comment: The page i linked to suggests you upgrade your git, try that

Comment: I upgraded it... It now works... thank you!!!